# Image in flexbox not resizing on browser resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

*Note: I asked a very similar question recently, but was downvoted as I used an external URL as supposed to JS fiddle*

I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="homepage-banner-contents">
    <div>
            <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/whiskers-sam.jpg" alt="logo" id="banner-logo"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #homepage-banner-contents {
        height: calc(100% - 60px);
        background: red;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-flow: column;
    }

    #banner-logo {
        max-height: 320px;
    }

    #banner-logo {
        max-height: 320px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anik786/9vd83rww/

**Goal**

My goal is to keep the image in the centre of the red background and for the image to shrink when the height of browser becomes too small.

**What actually happens**

Although the above code is okay for normal screen sizes; when the browser **height** is reduced too much, the image does not seem to shrink at all, but instead insists on keeping its same size, causing overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/9vd83rww/2/

```
#banner-logo {
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    max-width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: No as the image is pixilated and not kept in ratio when it exceeds a certain point. But close

Comment: So add a max height and a max width? If you want it to keep the ratio however you will need to use javascript.